Issues with downloading and saving files using expo-file-system and expo-sharing in React Native
I'm working on a React Native app where I need to download an Excel file from an API and save it to the user's device. I'm using expo-file-system and expo-sharing to handle the download and save process. However, I'm encountering two major issues:
Error: "Could not create asset"
    const handleDownload = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Permission to access media library is required!');
        return;
      }

      const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'report.xlsx';
      const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
        apiUrl,
        fileUri,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Accept: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
          },
        }
      );

      const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();

      const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
      if (asset) {
        const albumName = 'Download'; // Nama album di galeri
        let album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync(albumName);
        if (album === null) {
          album = await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync(albumName, asset, false);
        } else {
          await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
        }
        alert('File tersimpan di galeri');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Tidak dapat membuat aset.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error downloading file:', error);
      alert('Gagal mengunduh file');
    }
  };


MediaLibrary is for images and videos.

So what do I use to save the Excel file?
